# C# Process.Start Passing Arguments recursively

Tags: c#, arguments, recursive-query, process.start

I have this use case in which I have to run

ikvm.exe -jar XXX.jar,

where XXX.jar takes the string args as argument.

So how do I invoke Process.Start so that I can accomplish this.

Simply typing ikvm.exe -jar XXX.jar args does not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "ikvm.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar XXX.jar";
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    ...
}
```

Was this what you wanted?

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to call Process.Start recursively. e.g. proc1 takes 2 arguments arg1 and proc2. Now, proc 2 takes 3 arguments arg2, arg3 and arg4. I dont think I can do Process.Start(proc1, "arg1 proc2 arg2 arg3 arg4"). I also cannot call proc2 and then proc1. My particular use case is that I need to invoke a jar file (which is proc2) using ikvm(which is proc1), arg1 is -jar and arg2, arg3 and arg4 are arguments for the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Process.Start()` and pass it a `ProcessStartInfo` object with the command arguments An example is below from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

        Process.Start(startInfo);

        startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";

        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: This is also not what I want. Please see my response to Scott's response. In my case, one of the arguments is a process and this process itself has arguments. Whereas, the example you gave has the same process started one after other.